# Reloading images with Tkinter when clicking a button

Tags: python, tkinter

When I push a button, I want it to load and show `img.jpg`. When I push the button again, it will reload `img.jpg` and show the new image. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Improved grammar and clarified the intent of the post.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that the handler of the button is `clicked`.
To display an image you need a label. (This code is for Python 3.3)

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()

def clicked(label1):
    displayImage = PhotoImage(file = "The path to your image file goes here")
    label1.configure(image = displayImage)


label1 = tkinter.Label(root, text = "")
label1.pack()

b1 = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Display", command = lambda: clicked(label1))
b1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thank you, but I use Python 2.7